# Repeater with multiple Itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

How can I make a Repeater with multiple Itemtemplates ? And a template is choosed
based on some condition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a nested repeater in your repeater:

[http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/NestedRepeater/Repeater_within_Repeater_193.aspx](http://web.archive.org/web/20120924023940/http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/NestedRepeater/Repeater_within_Repeater_193.aspx)

But this starts getting really tricky!  I'd take a look at what you are trying to achieve and evaluate if this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create hidden panels with different layouts in your itemtemplate. Then you could decide which one to display based on 'some condition' from your code behind. Not a very elegant solution, but the first one that sprang to mind.