# Different Item Templates in Web Forms - repeater control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a repeater that renders text boxes for each item in my collection. However for some items I want to have a check box instead of the textbox based on the item's property. Is it doable or repeater can only work with one `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713771/repeater-with-multiple-itemtemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can have the repeater load a different user control depending on the item's property.